# Golang serve static files in different directory

Tags: javascript, go

I have a library for go webserver and contain js file as well, so this is supposed to be the directory trees of users app. `myapp` is users app and `mylib` is library that fetched through `go get`.

```
src
`-- github.com
    |-- mylib
    |   |-- myJSlib
    |   `-- myGOlib
    `-- myapp
        |-- main.go
        `-- static
            |-- index.html
            |-- js
            `-- css
```

The web server of user app will serve static html in `static` subdirectory via

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
```

My problem is i can't include the script of library into `index.html` because the `http.FileServer` serve in directory `static`. Naive solution is i move the root of `http.FileServer` into `src`. But this is not the solution i want because it's to verbose when include the script from `src`. The other solution is i tell the user move the js file into `static` directory, this is fine if user in production mode and i have minified version of my jslib but in development mode that require structured tree folder this is just can't solve it. Maybe i can separate repo for myGOlib and myJSlib and user can use `go get` to fetch the myGOlib and clone the myJSlib into static directory. But i want user just simply use `go get` and everything works both lib without structurize things again.

Any solution would be appreciate. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a second handler for javascript that serves from a different folder (which could even be configurable):

```
thirdPartyDir := "<configuration driven dir name>"
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
http.Handle("/thirdparty", http.FileServer(http.Dir(thirdPartyDir))
```

And then in your `index.js` you could include 3rd party code like:

```
<script src='/thirdparty/foo.js'/>
```

Comment: The solution seems logical, i have to tried it but i have difficulties when register second handler. It seems i can't register handler except for "/". I keep recieve this error in my browser `GET http://localhost:8080/thirdparty 404 (Not Found)`.